# DJango Post csrf_token invalid and /favicon.ico not found

Tags: javascript, django, csrf-token

I got a problem with DJango. Im trying to send data to a SQL Database in DJango. So I need my token, which I get with {{ csrf_token }}. But when I send the data on the HTML Website, it tells me POST 403 Forbidden and the DJango Terminal says NotFound: /favicon.ico, as well as Forbidden (CSRF token from POST has incorrect length.): /ausgeben/

Does anyone have a solution for this. Down below is the code I`m using for the token request.

Thanks!

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", name);
    formData.append("gewinde", gewinde);
    formData.append("laenge", laenge);
    formData.append("durchmesser", durchmesser);
    //formData.append("containerNR", containerNR);
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', token);

    fetch('/ausgeben/',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the `csrftoken` in the `fetch` headers rather than in the body of the request. Disclaimer that I haven't used this with `fetch` but it was necessary with JQuery and an `$.ajax` request.

```js
fetch('/ausgeben/',{
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': token
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, but it says "Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /ausgeben/"...

Comment: Got it. He couldn't read the Token. I importet him manually and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Add a favicon.ico

Long version :

Searching for more topics about CSRF issues, I found this one.

I think you are facing an old (but it seems still valid) issue with CSRF and some browsers. It is often related to the favicon.ico file but it could happen with other static ressources (like javacript sourcemap *.map files).

After accessing your page, the browser requests the favicon.ico. If the file does not exist AND the request is handled by your framework, it could lead to generating a new CSRF token, therefore making the one on your form invalid.

To quote another :

> 1. Users are assigned a session cookie when they land on a PHP page. A CSRF token is associated with a session when users visit the login page.
> 2. Favicon requests were going to PHP instead of a static resource. Normally that's fine, since PHP will see the cookie.
> 3. But since the request looked like it was for a static resource, Varnish stripped the cookies before passing it back to Apache/PHP. That meant PHP issued a new session that replaced the old one.

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3590328